# Crew Management

Tags: x-rebirth

Nice and simple: How do you manage your crew? I know you can talk to them but the options on what you can do are limited to 1 (firing them).

What else can I do and how?

Comment: you can also ask to see their skills, but that's about it from what I can determine

Answer (score 1):

The crew within your ships is quite limited, their real potential is there when you own a capital ship and have them working in it, engineer will repair your ship and maintainance on the cap ship it is, captain will drive the ship and do the basic trade command, defence officer will handle drone for defence but i havent witness it yet